# How to load a Java Class with JSF, which was declared in faces-config?

Tags: jsf

I have declared a java class in faces-config.xml. Here is the code:

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>javaBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>testpackage.ConcretJavaBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
<managed-bean>
```

How can I work with this class in an another java class, which was not declared in faces-confix.xml? How can I get this class by using FacesContext from JSF like this small example:

```
ConcretJavaBean bean = FacesContext. // what shall i do here?
```

Comment: Why you need to access it..for what purpose

Comment: I must work with values, which was saved in this class

Comment: So you need only the values the class `ConcretJavaBean` bean have right. are you trying to access it from another bean

Comment: That "another java class", what class exactly is it and how exactly is it invoked? What's the concrete functional requirement for this all?

Answer (score 0):

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ConcretJavaBean javaBean = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(
                      context,
                      "#{javaBean}",
                      ConcretJavaBean.class);
```

However, remember that this will only work if a FacesContext instance actually exists. If you call it in the same thread that is processing a request, you should be fine.